# IPv6 not working

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm unsure as to why this is happening... anyway, let me start from the beginning

### The Setup

1 * Dedicated server with a /29 IPv4 and /48 IPv6 (from Nocix (DataShack))

1 * CentOS 7 KVM host

1 * CentOS 6 guest

---

### The Problem

I have the /48 my provider assigned to me, and I have one guest on the KVM host. the guest works fine with IPv6 if it's on the same segment as the host, `2604:4300:f01::/48`

However, I can't ping it if it's on a segment such as a /64, such as `2604:4300:f01:5e::/64`

The VM is connected to the real world using bridged networking on the host.

I can successfully ping the gateway using the /64 as well as the host, just nothing outside.

---

### What I've tried

Nothing yet. I know nothing about IPv6.

---

### Output from comments

`ip -6 route`:

neo (host)

```
unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
2406:e000::300 via 2604:4300:f01::1 dev viifbr0  metric 0
    cache
2604:4300:f01::/48 dev viifbr0  proto kernel  metric 256
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101
fe80::/64 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev viifbr0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev viifv1001  proto kernel  metric 256
default via 2604:4300:f01::1 dev viifbr0  metric 1
default via 2604:4300:f01::1 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 100
```

trinity (guest)

```
unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 65536 advmss 65476 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 65536 advmss 65476 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 65536 advmss 65476 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 65536 advmss 65476 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 65536 advmss 65476 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 65536 advmss 65476 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 65536 advmss 65476 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 65536 advmss 65476 hoplimit 4294967295
2604:4300:f01::/48 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 65536 advmss 65476 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
default via 2604:4300:f01::1 dev eth0  metric 1  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
```

Comment: What does the routing table look like, from the host and the guest? `ip -6 route`

Comment: @JohnMahowald: I've updated it

Comment: What are the IPv6 addresses of the host and guest?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: Host: `2604:4300:f01::2` Guest: `2604:4300:f01::3`

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using automatic IPv6 addressing in the guest? A link local default gateway can be convenient.

Comment: @JohnMahowald I have no idea if that's even configured on the gateway...

Comment: If you want to use a different /64 for the VM, it sounds like your host should be routing the prefix to the VM rather than bridging. Also, which address is the /48 routed to? You need to configure that address as one of the addresses on the physical interface on the host.